# Is .NET Stopwatch standby/sleep/hibernate aware?

Tags: .net, stopwatch

Does `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` count time during computer stand by?

Comment: Interesting question,  I've only ever used Stopwatch for poor-man's profiling so this never occurred to me.

Comment: Good question.... try it and let us know :)

Comment: As you can tell from the answer, this is implementation specific behavior.  The counter is wrapped by the operating system's Hardware Abstraction Layer, giving hardware designers plenty of options to cut pennies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

Looking at the code in Reflector shows that if it is not `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution`, then it will use the tick count (in my environment, the value was `false` so it will use `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`):

```
public void Start()
{
    if (!this.isRunning)
    {
        this.startTimeStamp = GetTimestamp();
        this.isRunning = true;
    }
}



public static long GetTimestamp()
{
    if (IsHighResolution)
    {
        long num = 0L;
        SafeNativeMethods.QueryPerformanceCounter(out num);
        return num;
    }
    return DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does.  But very inaccurate.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, after a little testing it does *appear* to be counting, but it was way off.  This is what I did:

1. Wrote the below code
2. Ran it, and immediately put my computer in **Sleep** mode
3. Waited 10 seconds and brought my computer back up

The result was a shocking `Elapsed` time of over 4 minutes.  Way off.  So I wouldn't use this as any sort of benchmark.

Here's the code I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestingCode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch testing = new Stopwatch();

            testing.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop timer");
            Console.ReadKey();

            testing.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}", testing.Elapsed);

            Console.WriteLine("Done!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```